# assign a DNS resolver to one specific client

Tags: dns, redirection, windows-server

I have a device whose browser is hard-wired to the manufacturer's home page. Using the DNS server (Windows Server 2016) I can "spoof" it and redirect it to an internal web server. This is not ideal because it will affect all clients in the entire LAN. Is there a way to instruct the Windows DNS server to redirect the request only if it comes from a specific client?

Comment: There's a couple answer here (https://www.reddit.com/r/PFSENSE/comments/33ydn2/forcing_specific_dns_servers_on_specific_lan_ip/) that could interest you. One in particular proposes to create an exception in your DHCP static IP table for this one IP you want to "isolate". Worth a try. Problem is, you must first assign a static IP to this one device, based on its MAC address. Do you have the rights to do so? EDIT: described with more details here: https://forum.mikrotik.com/viewtopic.php?t=141616

Comment: you mean reserve a specific IP address to be assigned to the device with a specific MAC address? Yes, I can do that. What I (probably) cannot do, is to program the device itself to use a hard-coded static IP address. Also, can I use this trick with a Windows DNS server?

Comment: The IP address is assigned by the DHCP server, regardless of the version of Windows you run it on, so yes, if you can go into the innards of your DHCP server, look up the MAC address of the device NIC or WiFi card and set its IP. Then you enter the DNS settings of the IP in question, and you apply whatever DNS IP or name you want. Restart the device for the change to take effect.

Comment: it seems that a (halfway simple) was to do this is to specify a custom DNS server for a specific IP address in the Windows DHCP app, which in my case would be pfSense - which seems to be able to NAT a request to a different web site.

Comment: Whatever works best for you. Let us know how it went!

Comment: regrettably this does not appear to be workable. I will start another thread with more info